# Entity framework not including column in select statement

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've just added a column to a table that Entity Framework has mapped. Entity framework added the column to the model but does not include the column in it's select queries. This is the class that EF generates:

```
public partial class mj_bagasse_gc_sampledetail
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> FructoseArea { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SucroseArea { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> GlucoseArea { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> TrehaloseArea { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SampleWeight { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> TrehaloseWeight { get; set; }
    public string TriplicateIndex { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Sample_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> FructoseConc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SucroseConc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> GlucoseConc { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> GCIndex { get; set; }
    public string BottleNo { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SelectedSampleDetail { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SampleDetailRun { get; set; }

    public virtual global_global_sample global_global_sample { get; set; }
}
```

this is the XML for the mapping in the EDMX file:

```
<EntityType Name="mj-bagasse_gc_sampledetail">
      <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ID" />
      </Key>
      <Property Name="ID" Type="bigint" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
      <Property Name="FructoseArea" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="SucroseArea" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="GlucoseArea" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="TrehaloseArea" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="SampleWeight" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="TrehaloseWeight" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="TriplicateIndex" Type="varchar" MaxLength="2" />
      <Property Name="Sample_ID" Type="bigint" />
      <Property Name="FructoseConc" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="SucroseConc" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="GlucoseConc" Type="float" />
      <Property Name="GCIndex" Type="int" />
      <Property Name="BottleNo" Type="varchar" MaxLength="20" />
      <Property Name="SelectedSampleDetail" Type="bit" />
      <Property Name="SampleDetailRun" Type="int" />
    </EntityType>
```

You'll clearly notice in both instances the column "SampleDetailRun" is correctly defined. However, when I try to get a row from the table using the LINQ statement:

```
(from sd in Entities.mj_bagasse_gc_sampledetail 
                                  where (sd.Sample_ID == Sample.ID) && 
                                  (sd.TriplicateIndex == s) select sd).FirstOrDefault();
```

This SQL statement executes:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[FructoseArea] AS [FructoseArea], 
[Extent1].[SucroseArea] AS [SucroseArea], 
[Extent1].[GlucoseArea] AS [GlucoseArea], 
[Extent1].[TrehaloseArea] AS [TrehaloseArea], 
[Extent1].[SampleWeight] AS [SampleWeight], 
[Extent1].[TrehaloseWeight] AS [TrehaloseWeight], 
[Extent1].[TriplicateIndex] AS [TriplicateIndex], 
[Extent1].[Sample_ID] AS [Sample_ID], 
[Extent1].[FructoseConc] AS [FructoseConc], 
[Extent1].[SucroseConc] AS [SucroseConc], 
[Extent1].[GlucoseConc] AS [GlucoseConc], 
[Extent1].[GCIndex] AS [GCIndex], 
[Extent1].[BottleNo] AS [BottleNo]
FROM [dbo].[mj-bagasse_gc_sampledetail] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Sample_ID] = @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[TriplicateIndex] = @p__linq__1)',N'@p__linq__0 bigint,@p__linq__1 varchar(8000)',@p__linq__0=127,@p__linq__1='A'
go
```

The SampleDetailRun column is missing from the select statement and I cannot figure out how to get it to include it. I've tried removing the mapped table and re-adding it again. I've tried removing the column from the table in the DB and re-adding it again (even with a different name) but nothing gets EF to include the column in the select.

I am using EF5

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `SelectedSampleDetail` doesn't seem to be there either.

Comment: Hey you're right! I didnt even see that! Thats also a new column that I recently added, I haven't started using that one yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh. The EF meta data files (*.msl, *.csdl and *.ssdl) for the project using the EF data context were sitting in a different folder than those being updated when the EF project was rebuilt. When I copied them over to the project that was using the files it included the columns in the select statement.